# call async method without await #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I have an async method:

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateRequestAsync(string userName, string password)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return bool.Parse(stringResponse);
    }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
bool isValid = await ValidateRequestAsync("user1", "pass1");
```

Can i call the same method from an synchronous method, without using `await` keyword?

Ex:

```
public bool ValidateRequest(string userName, string password)
{
    return ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password).Result;
}
```

I think this will cause a deadlock.

**EDIT**

Calling the method like above makes the call never end. (The method doesn't reaches the end anymore)

Comment: I believe calling an async method without await will just cause the method to be called synchronously, the resulting behaviour would depend on what your method actually does.

Comment: I've tried it! It looks like the method call never ends

Comment: @Chris the method is always called synchronously. It just returns a task, that's the only difference. All the magic is in await, not in the call.

Comment: Ah I see, I haven't actually used async yet; I need to go and read more about the mechanics. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that your method will deadlock but this is a result from your logic not from the fact that you are calling it in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: @Stilgar If you run this code on a single threaded execution context, such as a UI thread, it will most certainly deadlock, because the thread is waiting for the thread to become available. If you run it on a threadpool thread, you're fine.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I will do next time, thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you call an async method from a single threaded execution context, such as a UI thread, and wait for the result synchronously, there is a high probability for deadlock. In your example, that probability is 100%

Think about it. What happens when you call

```
ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password).Result
```

You call the method ValidateRequestAsync. In there you call ReadAsStringAsync. The result is that a task will be returned to the UI thread, with a continuation scheduled to continue executing on the UI thread when it becomes available. But of course, it will never become available, because it is waiting (blocked) for the task to finish. But the task can't finish, because it is waiting for the UI thread to become available. Deadlock.

There are ways to prevent this deadlock, but they are all a Bad Idea. Just for completeness sake, the following might work:

```
Task.Run(async () => await ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password)).Result;
```

This is a bad idea, because you still block your UI thread waiting and doing nothing useful.

So what is the solution then? Go async all the way. The original caller on the UI thread is probably some event handler, so make sure that is async.

Comment: Got it. The solution would be to create a Sync and an Async method?

Comment: Some asp.net web api action filter doesn't support Async methods

Comment: @RaraituL That's true, and `.ConfigureAwait` might help you. But be careful: action filters should run fast. Using `.Result` will block a thread, and it is something that should be avoided, also in action filters.

Comment: No, `task.ConfigureAwait(false).Result` certainly won't work. It won't even compile, since `ConfigureAwait()` doesn't return a `Task`.

Comment: In my case I don't care if it blocks the main thread or not - it's process that is initiated manually once a week - good answer

Comment: Why have asynchronous Tasks if you have to await them?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn Some APIs don't offer sync versions of their tasks. For example the `UserManager` in ASP.NET has only a `GetUserAsync` method. I think it's perfectly fine to use the `Task.Run` construct to block the thread, if you are building a RESTful API that has no UI thread in any case, especially because the asp.net web API seem not to be designed for async entry methods, which would make no sense in any case.

Comment: If i call the method in a task like this Task.Run(async()=> {await MyMethod()}); this will run in a thread pool and the web request context will not wait for it to complete execution. I had a similar case where I have to send an email for an operation but needn't wait for the completion of the mail sending.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ArjunMenon I'm not sure I understand you correctly. I suggest you create a proper question using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. You will get more exposure and more answers that way. Comments are not the best place to ask new questions.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn When you await an async function (Function 1), the function you're awaiting in (Function 2) will immediately return (usually returning a Task), allowing other code to continue. Once the awaited function (Function 1) is finished, the code will resume inside the original awaiting function (Function 2). If you're familiar with Unity, it's basically a coroutine.

Comment: @Clonkex - thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

you could use `return ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Oh, this is really nice to look at and deserves more upvotes.

Comment: This does not seem to work. The process hangs, just like you would do ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password).Result. The "bad idea" of Kris' response does the trick: Task.Run(async () => await ValidateRequestAsync(userName, password)).Result

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked using  .ConfigureAwait(false) setting in the async call. I have something like

```
return await Entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(.....).ConfigureAwait(false);
```