# Set SynchronizationContext to null instead of using ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have a library that exposes synchronous and asynchronous versions of a method, but under the hood, they both have to call an async method. I can't control that async method (it uses async/await and does *not* use `ConfigureAwait(false)`), nor can I replace it.

The code executes in the context of an ASP .NET request, so to avoid deadlocks, here's what I've done:

```
var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
try
{
    // Wipe the sync context, so that the bad library code won't find it
    // That way, we avoid the deadlock
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

    // Call the async method and wait for the result
    var task = MyMethodAsync();
    task.Wait();

    // Return the result
    return task.Result;
}
finally
{
    // Restore the sync context
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(capturedContext);
}
```

Does this produce the same effect as if MyMethodAsync had used `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all of its await's? Are there some other problems with this approach that I'm overlooking?

(MyMethodAsync is completely unaware that it's being run in an ASP .NET context, it doesn't do any calls to `HttpContext.Current` or anything like that. It  just does some async SQL calls, and the writer didn't put `ConfigureAwait(false)` on any of them)

Comment: Alternative to null context is to use a single threaded context by using AsyncPump.cs by Stephen Toub: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/ 
AsyncPump will run all continuations in original thread. Setting null context I think is the opposite: continuations will always run in a worker thread. So yes, I think null context is the same as ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere. Both solutions prevents deadlocks.

Comment: I use a helper class in my MIT licensed open source project: https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/blob/master/ExchangeSharp/Utility/SynchronizationContextRemover.cs. Simply call `await new SynchronizationContextRemover();` as the first line of the async method that does not need to await back to the original synchronization context, great for API or other class libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you wrap this technique in a suitably named static function, I think your suggest is significantly better than `Task.Run`, even if still the lesser of two evils.

`Task.Run` has a number of issues:

- It is not clear why you are using it, you want to start a new task on a web server? This will be deleted by new developers fast if there are no comments. And then boom, difficult to diagnose production issues (deadlocks).
- It starts on a new thread pool thread when it doesn't need to until it reaches its first await completed continuation.
- It makes you block synchronously for the entire Task returning function, when from your description of the problem, the blocking is actually just part of the overall task. What is being encouraged here is **longer** blocking over async code, this is certainly not what you want.
- If you use it multiple levels, you are multiplying the problem (with `SetSynchronizationContext` there's no harm in doing it more than once).
- If it turns out that there was no blocking / deadlock where you thought there was, or it had been fixed, `Task.Run` now is introducing blocking over async, whereas `SetSynchronizationContext` will not cost you anything, in addition to the optimizations it makes by not resuming on the context constantly.

I also understand there is hesitance to make any recommendation given blocking on async code should be avoided at all costs, however you have made it clear you are aware of this and this is to fix a known case of this outside of your immediate control. I think the dogmatic attitude towards this topic is damaging to the .NET ecosystem.

Comment: I appreciate your answer focussing on the technical merits of the solution :) And I agree with you that the dogmatic attitude in the .NET ecosystem causes more harm than good. I forget where I first heard this, but the quote goes, "There isn't 'clean' code and 'dirty' code. There is code that works and code that doesn't." I still use the terms clean/dirty, but there's something to be said for focussing on function of the code, rather than form.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a library that exposes synchronous and asynchronous versions of a method, but under the hood, they both have to call an async method.

[The library is wrong to expose a synchronous version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). Just pretend the synchronous API doesn't exist.

> so to avoid deadlocks

There shouldn't be any problems with deadlocks if you call an asynchronous method that uses `async`/`await`. If it doesn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then it's not as efficient as it could be, that's all. Deadlocks due to `ConfigureAwait(false)` only apply when you're trying to do sync-over-async (i.e., if you're calling the synchronous APIs from that library).

So, the easiest and simplest solution is to just ignore the synchronous APIs, which are incorrectly designed anyway:

```
return await MyMethodAsync();
```

Comment: Even Stephen Toub concedes that sometimes you 'really do need "sync over async.'" I simply can't mandate that all other code (especially legacy code) be async; I have to provide a synchronous version. It's worth mentioning that the async function call only happens in certain cases. The bulk of the function really is truly synchronous; I just have this one corner case to deal with.

Comment: In short, I promise that I really am trying to be a good C# dev and follow the async/await best practices. But, in the very rare circumstance where you simply have to bend the rules, is my SynchronizationContext trick a decent alternative to Stephen Toub's "Offload to Another Thread" suggestion?

Comment: The library you're using is what is requiring that the code be made async; my first question would be why isn't the library still legacy? But if you insist on sync-over-async (which will impact scalability on ASP.NET), then either `Task.Run(...).Result` or temporarily replacing `SynchronizationContext` (which I would do in a `using` rather than `finally`) would work. I would lean towards `Task.Run` for code clarity even though it is slightly less efficient.

Comment: This is just a normal, run-of-the-mill mess that you encounter in the real world. The library underneath doesn't have synchronous versions because "we don't have the resources to maintain two copies of every data access function." This code is part of a three-tier caching infrastructure, and the bottom tier that does the SQL calls is the one that doesn't have a synchronous API. But we need to leverage it in some legacy code.

Comment: @StephenCleary What about situations where you are implementing a interface that has no async version. For example `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions<T>`, If I need to make a call in to a 3rd party library that exposes only a asynchronous method but does not reliably use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Because I am forced to do a synchronous wait, is using `SetSynchronizationContext(null);` the best of my available options to call that method without the risk of deadlock? I ask you because I trust your opinion on matters async.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: It depends on your environment and what the code does. Clearing the SyncCtx and blocking works in most scenarios; blocking on a `Task.Run` is less efficient but works in other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `SynchronizationContext` to null seems hacky for me. Instead you can really delegate the work to threadpool. Use `Task.Run`..

```
var result = Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync()).Result;
```

or

```
var result = Task.Run(async () => await MyMethodAsync()).Result;
```

This avoids the deadlock and eliminates the hacky code as well.

Comment: Why use an extra threadpool thread? this is a specially dangerous in a ASP.NET environment. how is this not hacky as well?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is regularly used practice. I'll try to find some source.. We're doing a remedy for someone else's mistake.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786441/call-async-method-without-await-2) about deadlock

Comment: This usage of `Result` is *not* going to deadlock because the task is guaranteed to complete eventually. It is not bound to the synchronization context currently active.

Comment: I see nothing in that question that makes it unhacky. Heck, i wouldn't even recommend doing so because it "just works". Even though something works doesn't mean it should be done. We dont know when/how the OP is using this code, and if this is provided as a 3rd party library, this is even more dangerous and questionable.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Explain a bit on why this is dangerous. I don't see the problem!

Comment: @usr Your comment is relevant only when `SynchronizationContext` is set to null. In my answer I don't recommend doing it. Am I missing something ?

Comment: When i use an async api, i *never* assume someone is using a new thread behind the scenes, may it be a threadpool thread or not. In an ASP.NET context, if you don't register that worker thread using `HostEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, IIS may decide to recycle your app without you ever knowing about it, causing unexpected behavior. I would definitely not want this being done by some 3rd party library i need to use.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no, I agree with you. This works. The 2nd code snippet of yours is not useful, though, because the additional task created there does nothing. It doesn't free any thread.

Comment: @usr Just realized, removed that.

Comment: Can you guys explain why you think setting the sync context to null is hacky? How is it any different than using `ConfigureAwait(false)` ?

Comment: @Ryan Setting `SynchronizationContext` to null you're lying that you're not in UI context when you're actually inside that where as `ConfigureAwait(false)` says that no need to capture the `SynchronizationContext` and you can continue the execution in default scheduler.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, but if the callee is not designed to be used in the UI context—does not try to access any objects that are locked by the UI’s `SynchronizationContext` or set some `Label.Text` property—then running it with a non-`null` `SynchronizationContext.Current` could very easily break it. Calling an `async` method and accessing `Result` directly in a synchronous method will only ever deadlock when the synchronization context is non-`null`. Why would an external library ever test that the functionality still works when a synchronization context is set if it’s not a UI library?