# Calling async function in a Razor View using a Custom View Base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

In my MVC5 application some view components do not get rendered in RAZOR if the user does not have the permissions for it.

The permissions are fetched using a Repository pattern which is completely async as the rest of my application.

I have implemented a IPermission Service that has the following methods

```
public interface IPermissionService 
{
    Task<bool> IsUserAllowed(string moduleName, string action);

    Task<bool> IsUserAdmin();
}
```

Now to be able to use this service in my view I have written a custom View Base which inherits from the WebViewPage as follows:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<T> : WebViewPage<T> where T : class
{
    public IPermissionService Permissions;

    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        Permissions= DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPermissionService>();
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}
```

I am not able to use these async functions from my View as await doesnt work there. I dont want to create a separate non-async implementation of the data repositories. Also I feel calling a async function without await by doing something like Task.Result() also is not a good idea as per [call async method without await #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786441/call-async-method-without-await-2)

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the retrieval of permissions a part of your controller logic, rather than view logic?

Comment: Yeah i would like to do that. but then how do i pass it to the view ? Viewbag ?

Comment: Also the permissions are loaded and stored in cache/session at user login. Its more of a IsAllowed() kind of check that i need to do in the view and dont want to have a block of code in the view. that was the main idea of writing that in a separate helper class.

Comment: @Yash: Any solution will be a hack for now. [ASP.NET vNext will have proper support for `await` in razor views](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try decoupling loading of these resources from the loading of your view.

Your view itself should load all items that all users have permission to.

As the view is rendered on client-side, send an async ajax call back to an Action on the server that will evaluate what the user has permission to see, and will return appropriate data/models for client-side loading.

This way you dont have to worry about running async server code in the view, and still have complete control of what the user can see (which is also async)

Comment: Well, I dont want to do that. Firstly because I feel not rendering a component (say not display an ADD button) is more secure. and also Its not just the permission service that i need to use. all my labels and captions come from the database based on the user's language preference. So I would like to use another service/helper injected into the view base to do this. Cant also make use of static functions as this needs to be per user instance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good candidate for dependency injection. For example, check out Autofac's suggestions for property injection:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-view-pages