# Returning value from a disposed method

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
public class HttpRequestsHandler
    {
        public static T HttpGetWithContent<T>(string requestUrl)
        {
            using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())
            {
                handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUrl),
                    Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
                })
                {
                    using (var response = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl).Result)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Gone)
                        {
                            var errorMessage = $"HttpRequestTask: Request failed with status {response.StatusCode} for URL: {requestUrl}";
                            throw new HttpException(errorMessage, (int)response.StatusCode);
                        }
                        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static T HttpGetWithContentWrapper<T>(string requestUrl)
        {
            return HttpGetWithContent<T>(requestUrl);
        }
  }
```

now when I call it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var url = UrlProvider.BuildRequestUrl();
            var date = HttpRequestsHandler.HttpGetWithContent<DateTime>(url);
            //More code...
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
           //more code...
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

it works like a charm, but when I do it with a wrapper method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var url = UrlProvider.BuildRequestUrl();
            var date = HttpRequestsHandler.HttpGetWithContentWrapper<DateTime>(url); //fails here
            //More code...
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
           //more code...
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

it ends with an error "Not acccessable area".

Now I guess it has something to do with disposable pattern with I;m not familiar with. from what I understand it is used for unmanaged resources in the application, so an object only lives within the 'using'.

what I don't understand is how it can return a value in the fisrt part but not in the second...

thanks,

UPDATE- My apologies, from manipulating the codes so much to get it work I pasted the wrong one, I changed it to the original code the gave me the trouble, thank you

Comment: The line `return HttpGetWithContent<T>(string requestUrl);` doesn't look right. Are you sure it shouldn't be `return HttpGetWithContent<T>(requestUrl);`

Comment: Just to make sure - the url is in both tests exactly the same?

Comment: Does that even compile using _"return HttpGetWithContent<T>(string requestUrl);"_ - I get _"Invalid expression term 'string'"_ and _"Syntax error, ',' expected"_ if I copy your code.

Comment: You have used `.Result` on a task in a Winforms-application, this will almost certainly deadlock. If you want to use async code you must use async code all the way up.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786441/call-async-method-without-await-2

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
public static T HttpGetWithContentWrapper<T>(string requestUrl)
{
    return HttpGetWithContent<T>(string requestUrl);
}
```

to

```
public static T HttpGetWithContentWrapper<T>(string requestUrl)
{
    return HttpGetWithContent<T>(requestUrl);
}
```

By writing `string requestUrl` as the argument, you are effectively passing an empty string to your method. Perhaps this is what is causing the error (assuming this mistake exists in your actual code and not just in the example).

Comment: Hi, I posted the wrong code, changed it to the correct one, thank you