# UI not updating when using async/await with multiple tasks

Tags: c#, user-interface, async-await

I'm writing some example code demonstrating async/await for a presentation I'm giving and for some reason the label contents is not updating as expected.

```
    private async void AsyncAwaitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AsyncAwaitButton.IsEnabled = false;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(this.IterationsTextBox.Text); i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(this.ReadTextAsync(this.dataPath));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(
            tasks.Select(
                async x =>
                    {
                        this.AsyncAwaitData.Content = $"Elapsed time: {DateTime.Now - start}";
                        await x;
                    }));
        this.AsyncAwaitButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (
            var sourceStream = new FileStream(
                filePath,
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.Read,
                bufferSize: 4096,
                useAsync: true))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                sb.Append(text);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now if I understand my own code correctly, the `Select` statement is creating an `IEnumerable<Task>` where each task is awaiting a corresponding task from the `tasks` variable populated by the preceding `for` loop. This `IEnumerable<Task>` is then passed to `Task.WhenAll`.

I would expect that due to the `await x;` yielding the thread, there would be ample opportunity for the UI to repaint to reflect the changed label content but for some reason it is only updating after all the tasks have completed. Even adding a `Task.Delay(1000)` doesn't seem to affect the behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the code for `ReadTextAsync`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've updated the code.

Comment: By ui updating if you expect/mean this `this.AsyncAwaitButton.IsEnabled = true;` to execute, it will NOT until all tasks have been completed.

Comment: @CodingYoshi It's referring to the updating of the label content: `this.AsyncAwaitData.Content = [...]`

Comment: Why are you performing work within a `Select`? It is for querying not for doing work. Anyways you have this code: `ReadTextAsync`, you need to read [calling async without await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786441/call-async-method-without-await-2) so you really understand whats happening. Also, for a presentation to present the concept of async/await, I wouldnt write all that code and try to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I'd hardly call awaiting an already running task "work". In any case, the `Select` is a simple linq projection from one task to another implicitly generated one. As for the complexity, I'm open to suggestions on how to further simplify an example intended to demonstrate awaiting multiple tasks and asynchronously updating the UI as each completes.

Comment: This may not be the only issue in your code, but currently all your work is running in the UI thread. You should add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your `sourceStream.ReadAsync`

Answer (score -3):

The code is running on an operating system that doesn't support asynchronous file operations, so `FileStream.ReadAsync` is running synchronously, despite having `Async` in the name and returning a `Task`.  Since the method is running synchronous, all of the methods that await it are *also* running synchronously, which ends up being all of the code you've shown.

Since you need this operation to run asynchronously, in order to not block the UI thread, you have no choice but to use `Task.Run` to call `ReadTextAsync` (or `ReadAsync` if you prefer) to ensure that the operation *actually* runs asynchronously.

Comment: Are there any tests I could do to confirm this is a file system problem? I'm running the examples on a Windows 7 machine, which should fully support async I/O but a quick search reveals that async operations can be executed synchronously for a variety of reasons. Since this is a demo I suppose I could simulate async I/O using `Task.Delay()`.

Comment: @KennethCochran The easiest way to test is is to look at the returned `Task`, before awaiting it, and check if it's already completed.  If it is,  you know it ran synchronously.